Difference between DTO (Data Transfer Object) and model class
While doing R&D about DTO, I am unclear about the difference between the model class and a DTO. I searched for some information about that.

Model - has the data handle and business logic
DTO - has the data handle only

I don't understand this difference, could you give some example for those two things?
From my understanding, both are classes with fields until getting a proper example.
I expect an example for those two things

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853749/what-is-the-difference-between-an-mvc-model-object-a-domain-object-and-a-dto?rq=2
Check this

This question is similar to: What is the difference between an MVC Model object, a domain object and a DTO. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i also checked that @Sohan , from that i get the information that the model have business logic and Dto don't
but i expect some example
